# How to display the contents of a openscenario file?

Tags: python

I am working with an openscenario(.xosc) file and there is a parser which converts it into xml using the pytress. Based on the below code, i am getting a config file.

```
<srunner.scenarioconfigs.openscenario_configuration.OpenScenarioConfiguration object at 0x00000125563FBA90>
```

Is there any way to dispaly what is the contents of the config. I know there is a field called 'name' which when i do config.name it returns:

```
[<srunner.scenarioconfigs.scenario_configuration.ActorConfigurationData object at 0x0000012556786D30>]
```

To find out the contents of the config file

Comment: You can try `help(yourObjectName)` to get an idea.